# Getting a 404 Not Found error with React Router

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm trying to set up a React app with React Router, but I keep getting a 404 Not Found error when trying to access some of my routes. Here's the code for my App component:

App.js

```
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Product from './components/Product';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import ProductCard from './components/ProductCard';
import ProductAnim from './components/ProductAnim';
import Horizontal from './components/Horizontal';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import About from './components/About';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Create from './components/Create';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Example from './components/Example';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/products' element={<ProductAnim />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path='/brew' element={<Product />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've checked that the URLs I'm trying to access match the path in my code, and I've also installed all the necessary dependencies for React Router. However, I'm still getting a 404 Not Found error when I try to access some of the routes, such as "/products". The error message I'm seeing is:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Can someone please help me figure out what's causing this error and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance for your help!